# Extract specific columns from text file OS X

Tags: macos, awk, terminal

I need to often and repeatedly extract specific columns 11, 12 & 13 from a tab delimited text file using OS X Terminal command to create a new file.

I have tried variations of this awk command:

```
    ‘BEGIN {FS=“\t”; OFS = “,”; print $11,$12,$13}’ input.txt > output.txt
```

Where have I erred, or What am I missing ?

Terminal just seems to "time out" and I must terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put all the code in the BEGIN section and use normal quotes (`'` and `"`), not "smart quotes" (`‘` and `“`):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS=","} {print $11,$12,$13}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This answered my question about my error(s) and worked as desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be happy to know, there's a specific command(s) for this.

See `man cut`
See `man tr`

```
cut -f 11,12,13 input.txt | tr "\t" "," > output.txt
```

Comment: not sure about other implementations, but with `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.25` you can do that... for ex: `printf '1\t2\t3\t4\t5\n' | cut --output-delimiter=, -f2,3`

Comment: @EdMorton, there's a command for that. ;) See `man tr` I'll edit the answer to include that.